# Searching for information about using info from form

Tags: php, html

I am modding the system. And i need some information. So the situation is this - I have got login form, and I have got index file which checks the inputed data if they are good like ( username, password ). I have created new select-box next to those inputs like:

```
Username:</p>
Password: </p>
Language: my select box </p>
```

I understood that index.php file which checks if username and password are good, ONLY checks but ain't using that info... So, in order to use that language select box i need to use that info not only check. How could i use that select-box value? I tried doing $_POST['language'], but that doesn't help.

Here is my index.php file https://jsfiddle.net/e40bsxox/1/

Here is my html file https://jsfiddle.net/fd8x94j2/1/

Comment: Pls show your index.php file

Comment: It's not big but i've putted it in https://jsfiddle.net/e40bsxox/1/ here. As you can see it checks data. And i need to use language selected value.

Comment: hi but in you index.php file I cant find you html code? we need it.

Comment: Here is my html file https://jsfiddle.net/fd8x94j2/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your HTML file code you have given the select field name as 'kalba'. So in you php file get the selected value by using the name as,
In html file,

```
<select type="language" id="kalba" name="kalba" class="text">
    <option value="lt_LT" selected="selected">Lietuvių</option>
    <option value="en_US">Anglų</option>
</select>
```

In php file use

```
echo $_POST['kalba'];
```